# error in making canvas view

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am trying to make an app which draw points on the screen for that I am trying to make `CanvasView`

```
package com.example.android.touchview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by Vikas on 7/26/2016.
 */
public class CanvasView extends View
{


    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();

   //private float[] points;
  //  float[] points={(float)2.25, (float) 2.55,(float)9.54,(float)5.55};
    Context context;




    public CanvasView(Context c,AttributeSet attributeSet)
    {

        super(c, attributeSet);
        context =c;


       // Paint paint = mPaint;

        //canvas.translate(10, 10);

        //canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        //mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Dbhelper db =new Dbhelper();
        float [] points=db.getData();



        mPaint.setStrokeWidth((float) 0.0);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);


        canvas.drawPoints(points,mPaint);
    }


}
```

and this is the `DbActivity` class from which I am trying to retrieve the array of points this class object I have created in the canvas view and trying to get the array of points

```
package com.example.android.touchview;

/**
 * Created by Vikas on 7/20/2016.
 */

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DbActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private float[] points;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_db);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SQLinfo);
        DataBase db = new DataBase(this);
        try {
            db.open();
            Log.d("hi", "Database opned");
            ArrayList<Float> data = db.getData();
            db.close();
            Log.d("hi","Databaseclosed");


           // data.toString();
            tv.setText(data.toString());


            points = new float[data.size()];
            Log.d("hi", "Arry created");

            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
            {
                points[i] = (float) data.get(i);
                String m= "points"+points[i];
                Log.d("hi",m);
            }


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public float[] getData()

    {
        Log.d("hi","method called");
        for(int i=0;i<points.length;i++)
        {
            String m = "points"+points[i];
            Log.d("hi",m);
        }
        return points;
    }
}
```

After all this I am getting `NullPointerException` in the `CanvasView` when I am declaring it in the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/points_canvas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.android.touchview.CanvasView
        android:id="@+id/signature_canvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Dbhelper.java

```
package com.example.android.touchview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Vikas on 7/29/2016.
 */
public class Dbhelper extends AppCompatActivity{
    private float[] points;


    public float[] getdata() {
      Log.d("hi","method called");
        DataBase db= new DataBase(Dbhelper.this);
        Log.d("hi","Database object created");
        try
        {
            Log.d("hi","in the try");
             db.open();
            Log.d("hi", "databseopened");
            ArrayList mPts = db.getData();
            db.close();
            Log.d("hi", "Databaseclosed");
            points = new float[mPts.size()];
            Log.d("hi","Arry created");

            for (int i = 0; i < mPts.size(); i++)
            {
                points[i] = (float) mPts.get(i);
                String m= "points"+points[i];
                Log.d("hi",m);
            }


        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return points;
    }


}
```

Basically I am getting these errors

> java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   com.example.android.touchview.DbActivity.getData(DbActivity.java:56)
>     at
>   com.example.android.touchview.CanvasView.onDraw_Original(CanvasView.java:49)

Basically  void draw method is not able to get array of points but how to solve it  and I am not able to understand what is the mistake please help 
thanks in advance

Comment: `DbActivity db =new DbActivity();` - You cannot instantiate an `Activity` with `new` and have it work correctly. Your `View` shouldn't be trying to directly access its `Activity` anyway. Pass the necessary data to the `View` instance through a public method instead.

Comment: can you please explain me by changing the code since I am new to android please help

Comment: Please edit your question to better explain your setup. Now that I look at it again, it seems that there is no `CanvasView` in `DbActivity`'s layout, and that `DbActivity` doesn't really need to be an `Activity`.

Answer (score -1):

CanvasView should be defined as an Activity since it draws the canvas in the layout. dbActivity should be used as a util class where you just get the data from database.

Make CanvasView as an activity. Inside onCreate() initialize database and fetch the data and store it in array. Use the array for drawing the canvas.

Make changes in xml too as per layout.

Comment: if I will make CanvasView as an then how will i override onDraw method

Comment: My main objective was to change the design. You can create a MainActivity class and go further. Here it seems View is not attached to dbActivity. Some application context is required to get the dbActivity instance. I'm not sure about it but as Mike said, you need to pass the context to View instance.

Comment: I have made an edit in my code I have created another class object Dbhelper in onDraw and i have also pasted the code of the Dbhelper

Comment: As you can see in that Dbhelper I have created a database object and I have tried to retrieve the array but after entering the try block when I am opening database it is not able to open

Comment: the log statements after the db.open() are not working